# How to deploy Node.js / React application to Heroku using Babel when writing ES6 code?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, heroku, babeljs

I have an application using React and Node.js. I'm struggling to deploy this to Heroku as I need to use Babel to transpile the code. Can someone help with setting the scripts I need to run?

I'm currently struggling to understand how to run client and server correctly as I'm getting an error regarding module location:

```
Error: Cannot find module '/app/build/index.js'
```

This is my package.json

```
{
  "main": "server.js",
  "scripts": {
    "server": "nodemon server/server.js --ignore './client/' --exec babel-node -e js",
    "client": "npm start --prefix client",
    "dev": "concurrently \"npm run server\" \"npm run client\"",

    "clean": "rm -rf build && mkdir build",
    "build-babel": "babel -d ./build ./server/server.js -s",
    "build": "npm run clean && npm run build-babel",
    "start": "npm run build && node ./build/index.js",
    "heroku-postbuild": "npm install --prefix client && npm run build --prefix client"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
    "body-parser": "^1.18.3",
    "concurrently": "^4.1.0",
    "express": "^4.16.4",
    "google-play-scraper": "^6.2.8",
    "googleapis": "^39.2.0",
    "is-empty": "^1.2.0",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
    "mongoose": "^5.4.19",
    "mongoose-paginate-v2": "^1.0.24",
    "multer": "^1.4.1",
    "node-fetch": "^2.3.0",
    "passport": "^0.4.0",
    "passport-jwt": "^4.0.0",
    "validator": "^10.11.0",
    "winston": "^3.2.1",
    "xml2js": "^0.4.19",
    "@babel/core": "^7.3.4",
    "@babel/node": "^7.2.2",
    "babel-cli": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.5",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-stage-0": "^6.24.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "eslint": "^5.12.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb-base": "^13.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.17.2",
    "nodemon": "^1.18.10"
  }
}
```

And the file structure of the important files:

```
node_modules
.babelrc
babel.config.js
package-lock.json
package.json

client
--package-lock.json
--package.json
node_modules
--src
----index.js

server
--server.js
```

I assume I'm setting up the scripts incorrectly.

Comment: did you ever figure this out?

Answer (score 0):

My problem was with some of the scripts. This is the final package.json that got it all working.

```
{
  "main": "server.js",
  "scripts": {
    "server": "nodemon server/server.js --ignore './client/' --exec babel-node -e js",
    "client": "npm start --prefix client",
    "dev": "concurrently \"npm run server\" \"npm run client\"",
    "start": "npm run build && node ./build/server.js",
    "build": "npm run clean && npm run build-babel",
    "clean": "rm -rf ./build && mkdir ./build",
    "build-babel": "babel -d ./build ./server -s",
    "heroku-postbuild": "npm install --prefix client && npm run build --prefix client"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.3.4",
    "@babel/node": "^7.2.2",
    "babel-cli": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.5",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-stage-0": "^6.24.1",
    "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
    "body-parser": "^1.18.3",
    "concurrently": "^4.1.0",
    "express": "^4.16.4",
    "google-play-scraper": "^7.0.2",
    "googleapis": "^39.2.0",
    "is-empty": "^1.2.0",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
    "mongoose": "^5.4.19",
    "mongoose-paginate-v2": "^1.0.24",
    "multer": "^1.4.1",
    "node-fetch": "^2.3.0",
    "passport": "^0.4.0",
    "passport-jwt": "^4.0.0",
    "validator": "^10.11.0",
    "winston": "^3.2.1",
    "xml2js": "^0.4.19"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "eslint": "^5.12.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb-base": "^13.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.17.2",
    "nodemon": "^1.18.10"
  }
}
```